# Is it possible to run Craft CMS with putenv() function disabled?

Tags: installation

I’m using shared hosting which supports several CMS like Wordpress, Jumla, etc. In `phpinfo` there is `putenv` in `disable_functions`. Craft CMS needs this function to load variables from `.env` file. I can acces all varibales at least from `$_ENV[]`.

Is there a way how I can install and use Craft CMS in this environment or is putenv(), getenv() must have?

Thanks a lot for help

Comment: In 2019, there are so many amazing managed and unmanaged VPS services, there's no reason to live with shared hosting. Check out [How Agencies & Freelancers Should Do Web Hosting](https://nystudio107.com/blog/web-hosting-for-agencies-freelancers)

Answer (score 0):

DotEnv only calls `putenv` if it sees the function is available since version 2.4.0, so make sure you're running at least that: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/commit/58633a061610ffd731d7fbbc8f7f009d14b2e4cf

Even then, I'm pretty sure other Craft dependencies (like Composer) will still require `putenv` support.